# Getting TextMate's RDaemon script to open R console properly

Tags: macos, r, textmate

I've run into an issue with the RDaemon bundle for TextMate, whereby starting up the RDaemon from the desktop icon opens the R GUI instead of being embedded in a TextMate project, as it is supposed to. I have tried trashing the RDaemon folder in Application Support, recreating it and the desktop launcher, but to no avail. Has anyone else run into this, and is there a solution. I hate using the GUI that ships with R for OSX, and so would like to restore this useful script.